# How to fix a double door that has shifted during the winter

Tags: doors, severe-weather

Like many regions, this was the worst winter we've had in 20+ years. Over the winter I've noticed that my double doors leading outside have shifted considerably. The top of the doors now rub together, creating great friction when opening or closing a door. In fact, it is occasionally very difficult to open or close the doors and requires a lot of force. On the other hand, the bottom of the doors have shifted far apart and there's now a gap of perhaps 1/2 an inch.

A few questions:

(1) I'm assuming the cold weather has caused this issue. Would this be an accurate assumption?

(2) Will the issue resolve itself as the weather warms?

(3) If the issue persists, what's the right way to fix the issue?

(4) Is this a symptom of a larger issue that I may be overlooking?

Thanks in advance for any and all guidance on this.

Comment: That sounds suspiciously like frost heave on the foundation.  What's underneath the door? What region are you located in?

Comment: We're up in Ontario, outside of Toronto. The door sits above an old foundation of stone. The house, and foundation, is 100+ years old although the door itself is about 10 years old.

Comment: It sounds like something caused the door jamb to rack or flare.  Check the top of the jamb to see if it's level and see if either of the sides are out of plumb.